# free() memory using a 'for' loop in a singly linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

This is my complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define kArraySize 50
#define kFirstElement 0

struct Name {
    char name[kArraySize + 1];
    struct Name *nextName;
} *gFirstNameNode, *gLastNameNode;

char GetName(struct Name *currentName);
void AddToList(struct Name *currentName);
void PrintList(struct Name *gFirst);
void FreeTheMemory(struct Name *gFirst);

int main(void) {
    struct Name *currentName;
    char character;
    int counter;
    gFirstNameNode = NULL;
    gLastNameNode = NULL;

    do {
        currentName = malloc(sizeof(struct Name));
        if (currentName == NULL) {
            printf("Out of Memory!\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            for (counter = 0; counter <= kArraySize; counter++)
                currentName->name[counter] = '\0';
        }
        character = GetName(currentName);
        if ((currentName->name[kFirstElement]) != '\0') {
            AddToList(currentName);
        }
    } while (character != '\r');

    PrintList(gFirstNameNode);
    printf("Freeing list memory");
    FreeTheMemory(gFirstNameNode);

    printf("\nFreeing Current Memory!\n");
    free(currentName);

    printf("Program Ended");
    return 0;
}

char GetName(struct Name *currentName) {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    printf("Enter a name (hit 'return' to exit):");
    for (counter = 0; (counter <= kArraySize) && ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); counter++) {
        currentName->name[counter] = c;
    }

    if (counter == 0) {
        return '\r';
    } else {
        currentName->name[counter + 1] = '\0';
        return '\0';
    }
}

void AddToList(struct Name *currentName) {
    if (gFirstNameNode == NULL) {
        gFirstNameNode = currentName;
    } else {
        gLastNameNode->nextName = currentName;
    }

    gLastNameNode = currentName;
    currentName->nextName = NULL;
}

void PrintList(struct Name *gFirst) {
    struct Name *currentPointer;

    if (gFirstNameNode == NULL) {
        printf("No names in list\n");
        printf("----------------\n");
    } else {
        for (currentPointer = gFirst; currentPointer != NULL; currentPointer = currentPointer->nextName) {
            printf("Name: %s\n", currentPointer->name);
        }
    }
}

void FreeTheMemory(struct Name *gFirst) {
    struct Name *currentPointer;

    for (currentPointer = gFirst; currentPointer != NULL; currentPointer = currentPointer->nextName) {
        free(currentPointer);
        printf(".");
    }
}
```

This is where I'm uncertain as to whether what I'm doing is correct. I'm teaching myself C all by myself so please bear with me. What I want to do is delete the node of the linked list from the first node till the last node. For that I created the following function. :

```
void FreeTheMemory(struct Name *gFirst) {
    struct Name *currentPointer;

    for (currentPointer = gFirst; currentPointer != NULL; currentPointer = currentPointer->nextName) {
        free(currentPointer);
        printf(".");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if by freeing the currentPointer whether I'm actually freeing the linked list. In other words I'm wondering if my logic is correct. I've got no one to ask so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: `c` in `GetName` should be defined as `int` and you should check for `EOF` in the while loop, furthermore the test on `counter` should be `counter < kArraySize - 1` and setting the `'\0'` should be done with `currentName->name[counter] = '\0';`

Comment: You need to store a temporary reference to the next node in the list as you free them, otherwise you will end up dereferencing freed memory

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem doing this:

```
free(currentPointer);
```

*followed* by this:

```
currentPointer = currentPointer->nextName
```

You can't deference `currentPointer` to get the next name *after* you've freed it.

Instead you should do something like:

```
currentPointer = gFirst;
while ( currentPointer ) {
    struct Name * next = currentPointer->nextName;
    free(currentPointer);
    currentPointer = next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question. Much appreciated.